# What tablets would be good for running Kubuntu Active?

Tags: kubuntu, ubuntu-touch, tablet

Looking at getting a tablet and installing Kubuntu Active Precise daily.

Which ones would run it best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the supported devices list in the Plasma Active web site.
http://community.kde.org/Plasma/Active/Devices

I think any tablet with the possibility to boot from an extern disk would work fine!

Answer (score 1):

Might not be what you are looking for, but there is a tablet out there that comes pre-installed with the Plasma Active desktop.

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/01/spark-kde-plasma-active-tablet-200/

http://makeplaylive.com/

Comment: Not yet, and it is really a rebranded Android, and not a particularly good one either. You. *can* Install mer/Plasma Active on the original, but I dunno about Kubuntu.

Comment: true the hardware isn't really on par with most modern tablets. Just thought I'd put the info out there

Comment: @MarcelCamaret: It's not rebranded Android. It's a conventional Linux distro running using a kernal compiled for Android. It still uses the GNU userland and runs native ARM apps rather than using the Dalvik VM.

Comment: no, not the os, the tablet is/was-going-to-be-until-problems another tablet that originally would have run android, with the android style home/menu/back buttons.